# Adding auto layout to buttons

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have an app where there are two buttons that I try to put auto layout on with a background image on each of the buttons. 
This is how I want it to look like:

[image]

But when I add these constraints in the storyboard:

[image]

This happens:

[image]

This only happens on an iphone 5 because of the screen size. Is there any way to make sure this doesn't happen by using different auto constraints that will keep the shape and put them in the right place?

Comment: It would be easy to give solution if you provide some more information like, do you want some fix height and widths to buttons and you want some some constant space between both or you just want to put them on edges of screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the iPhone 6 and 5s model has different screen width, that's why your UIButton is kind of shrink in width.

There are several ways to solve it, depending on how you want put the two buttons.

Let's say you don't care the space between the two buttons, then you can simply think about the first button is 5 pt. away from left edge, and the second button is 5 pt. away from right edge, then you are good to go (assume the Y position is unchanged)

You can also control-drag the related constraints into your .h or .m file, and manually change its value during layout to fit for different screen width.

BTW, UIButton and a few other views has `intrinsicSize` property calculated by default, if you want to leverage it, you need to read some docs about it and understand the content hugging, content resistance, priority concept to help you. I would also suggest you watch WWDC 2015 videos: mysteries of auto layout PART I and II